# Perguntas só com Fiddle

Tags: suporte

Aparentemente o filtro que impede a publicação de perguntas sem código e só com um JSFiddle (ou similar) não está ligado aqui no SOPT. Acabo de ver [uma pergunta assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31123/caixa-no-meio-da-p%C3%A1gina-de-acordo-com-a-resolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e exatamente hoje o JSFiddle esteve o dia inteiro com problemas.

A exigência de postar o código aqui é essencial para a pergunta não perder o valor se o usuário muda ou deleta o fiddle. E não é incomum sites populares sairem do ar ou simplesmente desaparecerem como o userscripts.org.

Será que isso só é possivel no Stack Overflow ou podemos ter esse filtro aqui também?

Comment: Não sei se já tivemos esse filtro ligado aqui algum dia, mas ele logo será menos relevante, quando [**isto**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) entrar no ar pra valer.

Comment: Yes, o SOFiddle vai ser batata, mas mesmo assim, o pessoal não consegue nem usar o editor WYSIWYG (wtf, programadores!), acho difícil que diminua a quantidade de Fiddle sem código... Filtro, please!